# Insert data and display on the same view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpqcL.jpg)I want to insert data and to show that inserted data from same view. We can use partial view. Please help, here it is giving error at the time of insertion.

[image: error screenshot]

**Entity class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace WebApplication7.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name plz")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**data layer class**

```
public class dlayer
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings\["connection"\].ConnectionString);

    public DataSet getalldata()
    {
        string query = "select * from employee";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        //cmd.CommandText = "select * from employee";
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();       
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }

    public string insert(Class1 cl1)
    {
        string STR = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into employee(Name,Address,email,phone) values(@Name,@Address,@email,@phone)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", cl1.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", cl1.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", cl1.email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", cl1.phone);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return STR = Convert.ToString(result);
    }
}
```

**default controller.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication7.Models;
using WebApplication7.DATALAYER;
using System.Data;
namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult Index()
    {
        dlayer dl = new dlayer();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dl.getalldata();
        List<Class1> products = new List<Class1>(); 

        foreach (DataRow dr  in dt.Rows)
        {

            products.Add(new Class1() { id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), Name = dr[1].ToString(), phone = dr[2].ToString(), email = dr[3].ToString() });    
        }    
        return View(products);
    }

        public ActionResult insert()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult insert(Class1 cls)
        {
            dlayer dl = new dlayer();
            string A = dl.insert(cls);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have a `Index()` GET method (the one you have shown is marked `[HttpPost]`)

Comment: but  how can we do both insert and fetch data on same view

Comment: You need to start by removing `[HttpPost]` from you index method (your getting data, not updating it!) But your code would never work correctly anyway (you need to pass a collection of your model to the view, not a `DataSet`

Comment: @radhasingh, remove `[HttpPost]` from your index method

Comment: i have changed the method of fetching data.but i want to insert data from same view.how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can `return View("Index")` to return index view and remove `[HttpPost]`.
Just ignore anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your code as:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
   // [HttpPost] /*Remove this to initial load of Index page with GET method*/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        dlayer dl = new dlayer();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds=dl.getalldata();           
        return View(ds);
    }

    public ActionResult insert()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult insert(Class1 cls)
    {
        dlayer dl = new dlayer();
        string A = dl.insert(cls);

     return RedirectToAction("Index"); //This line for redirecting to Index after Insert
    }
```

Instead of passing DataSet to View, You can create a ViewModel and pass it to view.